# Gunicorn memory usage and threads keep growing

Tags: django, memory-leaks, gunicorn

I'm running a Django app with Gunicorn in a Kubernetes environment. Since a few weeks the memory usage of the pods keeps growing. After looking into the process list I noticed that there are many gunicorn processes which seem dead but are still using memory.

The command I'm starting gunicorn is:

```
gunicorn app.wsgi -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.prod --reload
```

I don't know what is causing the growth of the gunicorn processes and how to avoid this behaviour.

Here is a screenshot of the process list:

[image: pod memory usage htop]

Comment: I see that you're using the `--reload` option which is only intended for development mode. Have you tried restarting the gunicorn process without it?