# gunicorn behind nginx high memory usage

Tags: python, kubernetes, gunicorn, aiohttp, locust

I have an issue with gunicorn behind nginx controller.
I have a microservice written in python with aiohttp and I am using gunicorn. That microservice deployed in a kubernetes cluster. I decided to test my app by doing some stresstest, for this purpose I used locust. The problem is: when I am running my app in a docker container locally, it shows pretty good results, but when I am doing stress test in a kubernetes cluster I see high memory usage by pod where my app is running. I thought that it is a memory leak and checked docker stats while stresstesting my app locally and it was using 80-90 MiB of ram. But when I am doing stresstest within a cluster I see growing memory usage on the grafana dashboard. Memory usage reaches up to 1.2 Gb and when I stop the locust it is not stabilizing and just jumps from 600 Mb to 1.2 and I see the spikes on the graph.
The pod is given 1 cpu and unlimited memory for now.
This is my gunicorn config:

```
workers = 1
bind = f"{SERVICE_HOST}:{SERVICE_PORT}"
worker_class = "aiohttp.GunicornUVLoopWebWorker"
#worker_connections = 4096
#max_requests = 4096
#max_requests_jitter = 100
```

I have tried different configuration of gunicorn with 3 workers (2*nCPU + 1) and max_request with jitter to restart workers. But haven't got good results.
One thing I discovered - when I am doing high load (500 users simultaneously) locust shows client timeouts with 'Remote disconnected'. I have read in gunicorn docs that it is a good practice to put gunicorn behind nginx because nginx can buffer the responses. And when I am testing locally or within a cluster I do not have errors like that.
The main question I have not figured out yet is why the memory usage differs locally and within a cluster?
With 1 worker when testing locally docker stats shows 80-90 MiB, but grafana graph shows what I have already described...

Comment: Welcome to the community! So are you checking the pod's memory only in grafana? I suggest logging into the pod via `kubectl exec` command and check what exactly happens inside and what exactly consumes memory + which container's runtimes are used locally and in k8s cluster? It can be different. Looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296742/gunicorn-memory-usage-and-threads-keep-growing) but it's not answered.

Comment: @moonkotte Thank you!
Today I did some tests. I run my app behind nginx locally and while it was under load I did `docker exec` into the container and run `top` command. So I was just watching master and one worker process memory consumption and it was stable, no memory leak.
But then I did exact the same thing within a pod. I started the load and run `kubectl exec` int the pod, typed `top` command and after a few minutes I saw growing memory consumption by a gunicorn worker process. 
Also I tried max_request with jitter and backlog, but It does not help.

Comment: There are some gunicorn issues related to kubernetes in their github project: [issue1](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2645) and [issue2](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2065), so if you think it's related to gunicorn I suggest asking in their github.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to @moonkotte for trying to help!
Today I found out what the cause of this problem is.
So, the problem is related to gunicorn workers and prometheus_mutiproc_dir env variable where the path is set to save counters data. I don't actually know for now why this is happening, but I just deleted this env variable and everything worked fine, but prometheus :). I think this relates to [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/275) and [this limitations](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-eg-gunicorn). Will dig deeper to solve this.